# [iOS]How convert Video to LivePhoto?

Tags: ios, objective-c, phlivephoto

How to convert a `video` to a `LivePhoto`?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you mean to ask, how to play video like facebook does?

Comment: No, Use ImagePicker.  VideoFile to LivePhoto(ios9)

Answer (score 0):

```
/// Requests a Live Photo from the given resource URLs. The result handler will be called multiple times to deliver new PHLivePhoto instances with increasingly more content. If a placeholder image is provided, the result handler will first be invoked synchronously to deliver a live photo containing only the placeholder image. Subsequent invocations of the result handler will occur on the main queue.
//  The targetSize and contentMode parameters are used to resize the live photo content if needed. If targetSize is equal to CGRectZero, content will not be resized.
//  When using this method to provide content for a PHLivePhotoView, each live photo instance delivered via the result handler should be passed to -[PHLivePhotoView setLivePhoto:].
+ (PHLivePhotoRequestID)requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)fileURLs placeholderImage:(UIImage *__nullable)image targetSize:(CGSize)targetSize contentMode:(PHImageContentMode)contentMode resultHandler:(void(^)(PHLivePhoto *__nullable livePhoto, NSDictionary *info))resultHandler;
```

Comment: But another app can convert. and https://github.com/genadyo/LivePhotoDemo project is possible. but i don't know objective-c convert.

Comment: can you give the URL..? Maybe they have created a custom component of their own. But I didn't see anything in the apple API.

Comment: and This App is possible. https://itunes.apple.com/kr/app/intolive-turns-your-videos/id1061859052?l=en&mt=8

Comment: and i find this way. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893993/is-there-a-way-to-save-a-live-photo-to-the-photo-library but not work.

Comment: The answer saves this data to photo library . There is no clue as to how they do it. Maybe you can look at my edited answer and use it

Answer (score 0):

using PHLivePhoto class method you can create any MOV video to live photo

```
+(PHLivePhotoRequestID)requestLivePhotoWithResourceFileURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)fileURLs placeholderImage:(UIImage *__nullable)image targetSize:(CGSize)targetSize contentMode:(PHImageContentMode)contentMode
 resultHandler:(void(^)(PHLivePhoto *__nullable livePhoto, NSDictionary *info))resultHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Converting a video is a little tricky task. The process is following**

1. first one *imageUrl* and one *videoUrl* is required to make a live photo
2. add one metadata to that image file which is *content identifier*
3. add the same *content identifier* metadata to the video file
4. add another metadata to the video which is the *frame timestamp* for the image which will be shown as thumbnail(the image used in the 1st step)

**After adding the metadata in the image and video file use the following api**

```
PHLivePhoto.request(withResourceFileURLs fileURLs: [URL], placeholderImage image: UIImage?, targetSize: CGSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode, resultHandler: @escaping (PHLivePhoto?, [AnyHashable : Any]) -> Void) -> PHLivePhotoRequestID
```

Please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35286486/2118280) which has a beautiful explanation of the required metadata for making live photo object.

And you can check the [following GitHub project](https://github.com/mamunul/LivePhotoCreator) for the code reference.

Answer (score -4):

There is no way to convert other files to `Live Photo` in newest iOS SDK, however some tool applications can do that such as [Live Studio](http://livestream.com/studio). And there maybe some tutorials online that explain how to make `Live Photo` from other files, which you can learn with. Perhaps you can excogitate one way with iOS.

Wish For You!

Comment: Thank you your Answer. i wonder is newest iOS SDK is no way? So, oldest iOS SDK is available?

Comment: I mean that newest iOS SDK doesn't provide simpleness API to directly convert files to Live Photo but there maybe some other ways, such as AVFoundation.Anyway, that needs learn more about `frame rate` or something!